# Paste Imported CSV to Last Row with VBA - "Subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

I was (reluctantly) nice to offer to help my HR department with creating a macro that will import an exported CSV from our accounting software to our existing Excel worksheet to track sales.

I thought I finally figured it out. But, now I'm getting subscript out of range errors when I import the data.

Does anyone see something I'm missing? Thank you.

Note: the staff barely knows how to use a computer, let alone excel. I'm not going to teach them how to use power query. I just wanted to have a nice button "update" they click on... select the file and done.

```
    Dim FileToOpen As String
    FileToOpen = GetFileName
    
    If FileToOpen <> "" Then
        Dim OpenBook As Workbook
        Set OpenBook = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        
        'Find last cell in CSV file.
        Dim Source_LastCell As Range
        Set Source_LastCell = LastCell(OpenBook.Worksheets(1))
        
        'Find last cell in reporting workbook.
        'ThisWorkbook means the file that the code is in.
        Dim Target_LastCell As Range
        Set Target_LastCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Services Data")).Offset(1)
        
        'Copy and paste - it's a CSV so won't contain formula, etc.
        With OpenBook.Worksheets(1)
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Source_LastCell).Copy _
                Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Services Data").Cells(Target_LastCell.Row, 1)
        End With
        
        OpenBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    End If

End Sub

Public Function GetFileName() As String

    Dim FD As FileDialog
    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    With FD
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            GetFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    Set FD = Nothing

End Function

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range
    
    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With wrkSht
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    End With
    
    If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
    If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1
    
    Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: **1.** On which line are you getting the error? **2.** Are you sure the workbook which has the macro also has the worksheet `Services Data`?

Comment: I'm getting the error on line 17. "  Set Target_LastCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Services Data")).Offset(1)" 

Yes, "Services Data" is a tab/worksheet within the workbook

Comment: I have rewritten your code. Posting an answer. Try that...

Comment: Siffharth... you were right. I found a spacing within the text of "Services Data ". The staff at this office has been doing that with everything. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: I'd love to see what changes you'd make tho, if you still care to share.

Comment: Sure. Shared it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Subscript out of range` on the below line

```
Set Target_LastCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Services Data")).Offset(1)
```

indicates that the code was not able to find the worksheet `Services Data`.

I would do this differently though. Does this help? I have commented the code so you should not have any difficulty to understand it. However, if you do, then simply ask.

```
Option Explicit

Dim NothingToCopy As Boolean

Sub Sample()
    Dim wbCsv As Workbook
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim rngFromCopy As Range, rngToCopy As Range
    
    '~~> Services Data worksheet
    Set wsThis = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Services Data")
    
    '~~> Browse to csv file
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Csv Files (*.csv), *.csv")
    If FileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub
    
    '~~> Open the csv file
    Set wbCsv = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    '~~> Set the sheet from where to copy
    Set wsThat = wbCsv.Sheets(1)
    
    '~~> Identify the range to copy and paste
    Set rngFromCopy = wsThat.Range(wsThat.Cells(2, 1), LastCell(wsThat))
    
    '~~> If CSV is blank then there is nothing to copy
    If NothingToCopy = True Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to copy"
    Else
        '~~> Identify where to copy
        Set rngToCopy = wsThis.Cells(LastCell(wsThis).Row + 1, 1)
    
        '~~> Copy and paste
        rngFromCopy.Copy rngToCopy
        
        '~~> Give time to excel to do the copy and paste
        DoEvents
    End If
    
    '~~> Close without saving
    wbCsv.Close (False)
End Sub

'~~> Function to find last row and column
Private Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim wsThatLRow As Long, wsThatLCol As Long
    
    With wrkSht
        '~~> Check if the worksheet as has data
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Get last row and column
            wsThatLRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                         After:=.Range("A1"), _
                         Lookat:=xlPart, _
                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False).Row
                         
            wsThatLCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                         After:=.Range("A1"), _
                         Lookat:=xlPart, _
                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            wsThatLRow = 1
            wsThatLCol = 1
            '~~> CSV has nothing to copy
            NothingToCopy = True
        End If
        
        Set LastCell = .Cells(wsThatLRow, wsThatLCol)
    End With
End Function
```